# Salesforce LWC : how to call a method of the loaded script in the javascript?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-dom

how to call a method of the loaded script function in the javascript? Ex: if I have loaded a script named ‘abc’. Now I want to call a method of the abc. Let the method be fgh. How do I call it in LWC?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are loading the script using the [LWC resource loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-resource-loader/documentation) then you simply call the function using its name. So, for a function fgh defined like:

```
function fgh() {
    console.log('called');
}
```

in a resource (script) loaded by the resource loader you call it by simply doing:

```
fgh();
```

Comment: Thanks @phil-w ,got it, to add ,below scenario.  static resource contains -- example     var x = function (a, b) {return a * b}; how can we call function assigned to variable

Comment: That's an interesting issue. IIRC there is a scoping issue here because the script gets loaded into a container; I suggest you try this out and use the browser developer tools to examine what happens during the script loading. I seem to remember having similar issues a while back when creating a PoC...

Comment: @rahuldeshmaane You have to either attach the function to global scope (window), or use the export keyword (`export { x as fgh };`). Otherwise, that function is local to the file and cannot be accessed outside of it. **Note**: This is a JavaScript behavior, and not an inherent limitation of LWC.

Comment: Thank you Phil and @sfdcfox, appreciate your comments, let me try these recommendations and get back to the same thread in case i get solution.